# how to retrieve a data value from database and store it in string?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I am writing code that retrieves a value from the database and stores it in a string variable and then later on displays it.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {    

        Int32 num = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        String s = Request.QueryString["field1"];

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string getAddress = "select Address from Patrons where Email='" + s + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(getAddress, conn);
        String addr = Convert.ToString(com.ExecuteScalar());



        Response.Write(GridView1.Rows[num].Cells[1].Text + " will be mailed to " + addr);
        conn.Close();


    }
}
```

When I run this, GridView1.Rows[num].Cells[1].Text  + "will be mailed to " is displayed. However, the address of the person having Email = s is not shown.

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but please use parameters to supply values to sql queries. (see http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: If you debug the program, and break after the ExecuteScalar, can you see a value in the addr variable?

Comment: Are you sure that value of `s` is an email address that is in that Patrons table and that it has an Address?

Comment: Have you run debug and made sure that addr is actually getting a value?

Answer (score -1):

> First you assign query string like below

```
Response.Redirect("Getvalue.aspx?field1="+txtEmilId.Text+" OR Database Retrive Value);
```

> use this code for get value from query string 
>       lblDispEmailId.Text = Request.QueryString["field1"];

Comment: this has nothing to do with the above question